# Insert multiple rows in mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, rows

I am working on a student management project on pdo php mysql. I need to insert multiple rows like student payable amount available to specific group of students. Or send a billing to a group of student. How do i insert this into sql database?
Is insert multiple rows a possible solution?

### Edit

My reference will be base from other table.. it goes like this.

table 1 -

```
-------------------------
| id | name     | group |
-------------------------
| 10 | John     | A     |
| 11 | James    | A     |
| 12 | Julius   | B     |
-------------------------
```

table 2

```
-------------------------
| id | stud_id | amount |
-------------------------
| 1 | 10       | 500.00 |
| 2 | 11       | 500.00 |
-------------------------
```

notice julius was not included since he has different group.

Comment: post your code and error you are getting if you have tried, or google for tutorials .

Comment: [`INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE GROUP = 'A'` - INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: one collects points in Answers @sean :) ... trigger finger waiting ... 78 more points ya know

Comment: @drew only if OPs actually select answers. Don't feel like wasting time giving complete answers when OPs don't respond to question/answers

Comment: plus he has a dangling one from a while back. The one where he said "Thanks! Kooilnc... have a great day."

Comment: @ParthChavda I disagree that this question is a duplicate of that one. VALUES() cannot be used here, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (stud_id,amount)
SELECT id,'500.00' FROM table1 WHERE group = 'A'
```

Comment: My reference will be base from other table.. it goes like this.

table 1
-  id  -   name   -   group -
   10     John            A
   11     James         A
   12     Julius           B

should insert on 
table 2

- id - stud_id - amount
   1   10           500
   2   11           500

notice julius was not included since he has different group.

Comment: I don't think the op can use values in this instance

Comment: check my updated answer @JohnArzaga

Comment: check my updated answer @Strawberry

Comment: Perhaps you should check it first ;-)